# ArcMap on Mac - How do I restore Identify Tool window that shows beyond the screen?

Tags: macos, windows-10, parallels

I recently installed ArcMap 10.4 on my Mac (OS X 10.11.3) using Parallels. 
When I opened Identify Tool, the window opened beyond the screen, and I cannot reduce the size, as the 'minimize' or 'restore' icon is not visible because the window had expanded too far.
I tried three different things:
 a) adjusting screen resolution,
 b) Zooming,
 c) script editor to tell ArcMap to keep window in a certain size etc.
The problem still remains. I restarted the program, but since my piece of work was already saved when closing the program last time, the Identify Tool window pops up (beyond the screen) every time I try to start the program, and I cannot go further unless I am able to close the identify tool window.

(I had similar problem with Attribute Table - when I expanded it, it displayed beyond the screen, and could not close/minimize. For this, adjusting screen resolution help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the help through GeoNet (Esri community) following the instruction below:

"On a windows box one would fix the identify window issue by opening the windows registry using regedit.exe and going to this key and adjusting the value:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.4\Controls\Commands\MapInquiry\IdentifyDialog\IdentifyDialogWindowPos:
0,0,405,372
The 0,0 is the position and the 405,372 is the size."